# Getting Unchecked return value from library?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

> Calling remove(file.txt) without checking return value. This library function may fail and return an error code

I am getting above warning in below code-

```
bool chkfile() {
  std::remove(file.txt);
  return true;
}
```

How should I remove this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) to see the issue. You have to check if there is no issue during remove operation.

Your code should be something like this,

```
bool chkfile() {
  if (std::remove("file.txt") != 0) {
    // error handling
  } else {
    // success
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: can I write like this if(std::remove(file.txt) != 0) { ; } in one line

Comment: or can i type cast it statict_cast<bool>(std::remove(file.txt); to remove the warning

Comment: You can write as the first option.

Comment: type casting can also be done to remove the warning if we tell complier about the return type ? @starboy_b

Comment: Yes, we can, I was just telling you that we can go ahead with the first option as well.